# How to have datepicker as dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know how to bind jquery datepicker to text box.

but my requirement is i need to display date in dropdown box.

**`Like <dd> <mm> <yyyy>.`**

I have gone through the following link, but is there any better way of doing this?

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-need-separate-month-day-year-fields-in-my-form-instead-of-one-field-for-all-three

Please Help me with this...

Comment: I think you'll have to explain that better? If something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwSYA/) is what you're after, why use a datepicker at all?

Comment: Like that i need date and year also. How should i add it? Using option tag? i need one reference to access this datepicker element. I don't want to take value from each dropdown button and making proper date. Can we do it in any other way?.

Comment: Nope, you'd create three dropdowns with the values you need, and then just parse it as a date. The datepicker is just a fancy UI with some added functionality, if you don't need the UI there's no good reason to add jQuery UI just to parse a date ?

Comment: Thanks adenoe... But, year dropdown should display years based on some condition. In jquery datepicker we can provide conditions, how we can manage that here? For example: the year should't display future year and it should display year starting from 1901 .

Comment: How hard can it be to create your own functionality, something like this ***http://jsfiddle.net/dwSYA/2/***

Answer (score 0):

I am not clearly understanding your question , But as understand it should be something like this.

$( "#date_picker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});

var date = $( "#date_picker" ).val();

var newDate = new Date (date);

var year = new Date(newDate.getFullYear());

var month  = newDate(newDate.getMonth());

var date = newDate(newDate.getDate());